# Change from @Enumerated to @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) on database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the annotation @Enumerated over some fields in an application thats already working. I was told to change it to @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) to prevent problems if the enum values change. The database is already populated, so the question is

What would be a good way to change the values on the database from 1,2,3.. to their corresponding String values of the Enum class?

Comment: A SQL update statement?

Comment: @Steven the column will only accept number values, I can't update these values to string

Comment: Then you can't use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. That setting tells JPA to persist the name of the enum constant as a string. The alternative is to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`, as you are which persists the enum based on its ordinal position.

Comment: @Steven Well yes, that's what the question was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how you can maintain the values and change the DB than I think you have to do it in a few steps(the basic algorithm to switch values):

1. Add a new column to your table that will be numerical.
2. Copy the values from your column to the new one.
3. Delete all the content of your column
4. Alter the table to make it a string column
5. Copy the values from the back up column back to the original one.

This is very detailed and I am not sure if this is what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

When you mark this Annotation, your ORM library should automatically try to convert String to Enum values using Enum.valueOf() function.
So your DB should contain the String form of your Enum ie the toString()/name() representation of Enum values.

Comment: The string values in DB should be similar to Enum values, suppose your enum is MY_ENUM in your java enum class, then your DB should hold a string with value MY_ENUM in its varchar column.